# Why is WM_NAME atom not set for certain locales

Tags: java, swing, x11

I recently discovered that the X11 atom WM_NAME is not set in Swing JFrame when LANG is set to `C.utf8` but is set for other values of LANG. This occurs on Linux Redhat 8.2 with OpenJDK 11.0.9.

Result with `xprop | grep -i name` when LANG=C.utf8

```
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "title 123"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "title 123"
```

Result with `xprop | grep -i name` when LANG=en_GB.UTF-8

```
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "title 123"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "title 123"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "title 123"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "title 123
```

Simple JFrame with title used

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new javax.swing.JFrame("title 123").setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've traced this through to [sun.awt.X11.XBaseWindow.updateWMName()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/bb9d142759ece7665329b124a8ea0b16049b024a/src/java.desktop/unix/classes/sun/awt/X11/XBaseWindow.java#L668) which updates both VM_NAME and _NET_WM_NAME unconditionally

```
XAtom nameAtom = XAtom.get(XAtom.XA_WM_NAME);
nameAtom.setProperty(getWindow(), name);
XAtom netNameAtom = XAtom.get("_NET_WM_NAME");
netNameAtom.setPropertyUTF8(getWindow(), name);
```

So I'm guessing that somewhere lower in X11 libraries the atom is either not being set or being rejected, possibly to do with character encoding.

I do understand that WM_NAME is legacy and optional and _NET_WM_NAME is the modern replacement. The reason this matters to me is that I maintain some legacy bespoke window manager style code that only looks for WM_NAME. I will be shortly enhancing this to look for _NET_WM_NAME too. I just want to understand this fully for my own academic geeky interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing further `sun.awt.X11.XAtom.setProperty(long, String)` calls out to native method `sun.awt.X11.XlibWrapper.SetProperty(long, long, long, String)`

This is implemented by https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.desktop/unix/native/libawt_xawt/xawt/XlibWrapper.c

```
#ifdef X_HAVE_UTF8_STRING
    status = Xutf8TextListToTextProperty((Display *)jlong_to_ptr(display), &cname, 1,
                                   XStdICCTextStyle, &tp);
#else
    status = XmbTextListToTextProperty((Display *)jlong_to_ptr(display), &cname, 1,
                                   XStdICCTextStyle, &tp);
#endif

if (status == Success || status > 0) {
    XChangeProperty((Display *)jlong_to_ptr(display), window, atom, tp.encoding, tp.format, PropModeReplace, tp.value, tp.nitems);
    if (tp.value != NULL) {
        XFree(tp.value);
    }
}
```

This implies that if Xutf8TextListToTextProperty is unsuccessful then no error is reported.

Xutf8TextListToTextProperty is provided by Xutils.h which comes from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11

It appears that libX11 has its own i18n implementation and until libX11 1.7.1 it did not "understand" LANG=C.utf8, although it did have an alias for C.UTF-8, this was corrected by commit https://github.com/mirror/libX11/commit/cc9f8878f2cbe17c7b4035b4ff4352b52ece38e0 which added an alias to /usr/share/X11/locale/locale.alias

```
C.utf8:                     en_US.UTF-8
```

The commit message answers the question concisely

> The normal form is 'C.UTF-8', but 'C.utf8' has been seen in the wild.

If I manually change /usr/share/X11/locale/locale.alias and run my example with LANG=C.utf8 then WM_NAME and other atoms are set correctly.